# Rest_framework datas from list

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

django rest_framework works very well if the datas You would like to expose are coming from the database, but what' s the situation if the datas are coming from simply a list (of dictionaries)? Is there any support in rest_framework to represent datas like this?:

```
[
    {'id': 1, 'name': 'apple'},
    {'id': 2, 'name', 'banana'},
    {'id': 3, 'name': 'orange'},
]
```

.

What would be the best way to achieve my goal if it' s sure the datas will never change (so no need to put them into the db as we' re talking about only less than 10 elements)?

I guess to convert the list to a fake QuerySet in django 1.6+ is not possible anymore... .

Rest_framework version: 3.1.1
Django version: 1.7.x

.

Comment: Serializers work with any kind of object, not necessarily a django model: If you look the second paragraph of this [docs page](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/) you can see that they define an arbitrary object and serialize it. In your case I would do the same, use your list to init a custom object that you serialize.

Comment: Well, this is an easy and very good solution for my goal, but in this case how do You turn on the pagination?

Comment: I mean i' ve the Page object (django.core.paginator.Page), and in rest_framework version < 3 i could use self.get_pagination_serializer(page) to get a serializer instance (with pagination), but what about it in 3.1? What (how) can i use instead?

Comment: I don't know about prior versions of the rest framework but in the latest version you can just set a [pagination_class](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/pagination/#modifying-the-pagination-style) in a generic view from the rest framework. In your case probably you will have to override the `get_queryset` method in the generic view since you don't really have a queryset. If you need I can add a short example in the answer.

Comment: I' d be glad for the example. Thanks.

Comment: At the moment my testcode looks like [this](http://pastebin.com/QDBWqXcS) , however it doesn' t have pagination which is my problem.

Comment: For some reason if i rename the `get` method to `get_queryset` and i return just the list of datas, pagination works well... .

Comment: Yes, i'm adding a detailed answer you you can understand properly what is going on. That is the way to go btw. Also don't forget to edit your question with the pagination stuff and your view code from pastebin, so it will be easier for people to read when they see the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For arbitrary objects you need to just follow the documentation:

```
from rest_framework import serializers

class Fruit(object):
    def __init__(self, id, name):
        self.id = id
        self.name = name

class FruitSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    id = serializers.IntegerField()
    name = serializers.CharField(max_length=200)
```

and then:

```
fruits = [Fruit(id=1, name="apple"),
          Fruit(id=2, name="banana"),
          Fruit(id=3, name="orange"),]

serializer = FruitSerializer(fruits, many=True)
serializer.data
# [
#     {'id': 1, 'name': 'apple'},
#     {'id': 2, 'name': 'banana'},
#     {'id': 3, 'name': 'orange'}
# ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Serializers work with any kind of object, not necessarily a django model: If you look the second paragraph of this [docs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#declaring-serializers) page you can see that they define an arbitrary object and serialize it.

Your pastebin for pagination is mostly correct, the only thing that you are missing is a bit of the inner working of generic views.

### Short answer

```
# define custom model for your list object
class ListElement(object):
    def __init__(self, id, name):
        self.id = id
        self.name = name

# define your serializer normally
class ListSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    id = serializers.IntegerField()
    name = serializers.CharField(max_length=50)

class MyListView(generics.ListAPIView):
    pagination_class = LargeSet
    serializer_class = ListSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        dt = [{'name': 'apple', 'id': 1}, 
              {'name': 'banana', 'id': 2},
              {'name': 'pear', 'id': 3}, 
              {'name': 'plum', 'id': 4}]
        return dt
```

### Long answer

Serializers just work on any generic object, they are not tied to django querysets or models, so you can serialize any custom object, as shown above.

I'll add some context first: generic views inherit some mixins that adds each some helper functionality.
For instance, in your case you have the ListAPIView which is defined like this: `class ListAPIView(mixins.ListModelMixin, GenericAPIView)`.

Let's have a look at the List mixin [docs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#listmodelmixin):

> Provides a .list(request, *args, **kwargs) method, that implements
>   listing a queryset.
>   If the queryset is populated, this returns a 200
>   OK response, with a serialized representation of the queryset as the
>   body of the response. The response data may optionally be paginated.

You could take my word that the `list` method also handles the pagination for you, however we can have a look at the sources as they offer a good idea of how things [work inside](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/mixins.py):

```
def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())

    page = self.paginate_queryset(queryset)
    if page is not None:
        serializer = self.get_serializer(page, many=True)
        return self.get_paginated_response(serializer.data)

    serializer = self.get_serializer(queryset, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

The code is quite clear, just notice that it uses the `get_queryset` method.

Now, you may wonder why in the short answer I did not use the `list` method in the `get` request handler of the view. The reason is simple, the `ListAPIView` does this for you already!

```
# get method of the ListAPIView
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.list(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

So the only thing that is left to do is to specify:

- the pagination class
- the queryset
- the serializer class

as the `genericAPIView` expects to see them.
The pagiation class and the serializer class are always the same, so you can just put them in the appropriate class property (`pagination_class` and `serializer_class`); if this wasn't the case you would have overridden the `get_serializer_class` and defined a property getter for the `pagination_class` (but this is a different story).

How about the queryset then?

Since you are generating the queryset dynamically, you cannot set it with the `queryset` class property, instead we override the `get_queryset` method (which is called above in the sources, if you recall) and do whatever we need to fetch our queryset and return it.

Hence the code in the short answer.

### There's more of it

There are [viewsets](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/) that do even more plumbing for you as they inherit from all the standard mixins and let you handle your request in higher level methods such as **list**, **create**, **destroy**, etc.

You can also find most of the useful methods that the `genericAPIView` offers in the [docs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#api-reference)

You can of course use mixins to provide a subset of what the `ModelViewSet` does, in case you come up with some weird combination of operations

```
# this one will provide the create and list methods only
# In fact it is the viewset equivalent of the ListCreateAPIView
class ListCreateViewSet(mixins.CreateModelMixin,
                        mixins.ListModelMixin,
                        GenericViewSet):
```

Hope this helps you understand a bit better the internals of the rest framework views!